# Trouble with using PyQt threads - receiving GTK errors

Tags: python, pyqt, qthread

I've almost managed to write my simple torrent client, but again some awful problems occured.
Here is a link to the code:
http://pastebin.com/Jyzrm0Vc 
When I turn on this app, sometimes it runs quite normally, but frequently I receive errors like this:

```
(python:8149): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_get_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(python:8149): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_tree_model_filter_iter_next: assertion `GTK_TREE_MODEL_FILTER (model)->priv->stamp == iter->stamp' failed

(python:8149): Gtk-CRITICAL **: /build/buildd/gtk+2.0-2.24.17/gtk/gtktreeview.c:6305 (do_validate_rows): assertion `gtk_tree_model_iter_next (tree_view->priv->model, &iter)' failed.
There is a disparity between the internal view of the GtkTreeView,
and the GtkTreeModel.  This generally means that the model has changed
without letting the view know.  Any display from now on is likely to
be incorrect.

[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
```

or like this:

```
(python:8131): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_get_visible: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

or this:

```
Xlib: sequence lost (0x1032d > 0x338) in reply type 0x1c!

[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
```

I suspect the Qt threads being faulty, but don't know how to fix this.
What's suprising me - these errors are about some GTK stuff, which I don't even use in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS are you running?  If it is ubuntu or ubuntu based or the shell used by the os is written using  GTK such errors are common in all applications. You can safely ignore them as long as your app is running normally.